# Android Kafka consumer integration problems

Tags: android, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to integrate kafka on Android app in order to be able to consume messages from a kafka topic.
I have successfully added the kafka dependencies to build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.10.2.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-streams', version: '0.10.2.0'
```

but when the app is starting the following errors are displayed in console:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.management.DynamicMBean" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kafka.subscriber-Eurshxgjwg0oFE6vcMCe0g==/base.apk"`

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.kafka.subscriber.news, PID: 9193
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
                      at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.unregisterAppInfo(AppInfoParser.java:65)
                      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:1568)
                      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:715)
                      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:597)
                      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:579)`

Here is a dummy code that I'm trying to run:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:8080");
    properties.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String,String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
}
```

}

Is someone who has an idea to resolve the above errors ? 
I have need to consume messages from the kafka topic.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't want to do this for 1) high volume traffic 2) Android can switch networks really easily between mobile and wifi, and you're going to need bootstrap servers to be resolved by both 3) A long running producer thread will drain the battery, and you must do it in an AsyncTask, not the main UI. Also localhost **always** means the Android device itself, and Kafka runs on 9092 by default

Comment: I want to use kafka on android only to consume messages. Is there a solution to consume messages from a topic?

Comment: I can see that, based on your code. And I specified three reasons you wouldn't want to do that even if the code did compile... Android may run Java, but it does not have all the necessary packaging to run a Kafka client. I would suggest using a REST proxy. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Comment: @pcCC28 how you solve this problem because i want to perform Android Kafka consumer integration

Comment: @cricket_007 I also need to run Android device as both producer and consumer. As far as i know Twitter uses it but i'm not able to find any tutorials about how you use Kafka  neither consumer nor producer. Is there any tutorial for Kafka on Android?

Comment: @Thracian it won't compile because Android SDK does not have javax classes ... You will need to use Kafka REST Proxy or use MQTT kafka connector

Comment: @cricket_007 We are already using MQTT but contractee, which is the biggest GSM operators country i live, so we don't have a say so unless we have a very good counter argument, decided that we should use Kafka instead of  it. So i'm doing research Kafka. Would you mind  pointing me to any document or source about kafka connector? I have only seen java examples so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Thracian Confluent documentation is exactly what I would point you to. Nifi, Streamsets, and possibly other streaming tools also provide MQTT and Kafka integration

Comment: @pcCC28 could you please share the proper steps to integrate kafka producer and consumer in android, actually i am also implementing kafka but not able to get any example in android so i am not able to so could you please share.

Comment: Hello,some one have solution or direction for indicate?